# newman.run in NodeJS module does not work

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, bluebird, newman

I want to execute `newman` from node.js module but it dose not work. and no error shown.

working well from command line

```
newman run postman-tests/collection.json -e postman-tests/environment.json
// newman installed globally for this command
```

but bellow node module code not working:

```
var newman = require('newman'),
    Promise = require('bluebird'),
    newmanRun = Promise.promisify(newman.run);

//.. other working grunt task here ...
// added new task postman-test

grunt.registerTask('postman-test','postman task running ',  function() {
    Promise.coroutine(function*() {
        try {
            console.log('test start-----');
            var response = yield newmanRun({
                collection: require('./postman-tests/collection.json'),
                environment: require('./postman-tests/environment.json'),
                reporters: 'cli'
            });
            console.log('run complete-----', response);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('postman test catch error: ', e);
        }
    })();
});
```

when I run "grunt postman-test" command shown in console `"test start-----"` only and shown `Done, without errors.` but no test execute

**whats wrong in my code ?  can any one help me?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, grunt treats all task registrations synchronously.Chances are this is happening because you have forgotten to call the `this.async` method to tell Grunt that your task is asynchronous.For simplicity's sake, Grunt uses a synchronous coding style, which can be switched to asynchronous by calling `this.async()`within the task body. doc [link](http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#why-doesn-t-my-asynchronous-task-complete)

```
grunt.registerTask('postman-test', function() {
        var done = this.async();// added this line
        Promise.coroutine(function*() {
            try {
                yield newmanRun({
                    collection: "./postman-tests/0.8/Meed-Services-0.8.postman_collection.json",
                    environment: "./postman-tests/0.8/local.postman_environment.json",
                    reporters: 'cli'
                });
                console.log('*******postman test complete********');
                done();
            } catch (e) {
                console.log('postman test catch error: ', e);
                done(false);
            }
        })();
    });
```